# Why don't you use the particle の when stating the name of a place?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, particle-の, names

I got confused when i was asked why you dont put の in place's name. it happen when I explain the function of の particle.
can someone tell me in **bunpou teki's** way, why name place don't use no?
like this example, it called みどり図書館 not みどりの図書館
thank you!

Comment: It's not too different from English using London Bridge instead of Bridge of London. Are you specifically asking about みどり図書館 or formation of place names in general? In case of the latter, it's better you provide some more examples you have in mind.

Comment: 「東京大学」と「東京の大学」はえらい違いですしねぇ‥

Comment: @sundowner I specifially asking about the formation of place names in general. like why its サクラ学校 not　サクラの学校.  or why itsIMC会社 not IMC の会社。

Comment: サクラの学校 sounds like a school for cherry trees: "for" in the sense of maybe someone wants to study cherry trees or in a children's book it's the school all the cherry trees attend.  Or, it sounds like a school constructed out of cherry trees.  サクラ学校 sounds like a name just like London Bridge.  Compared to when used with の, this usage sounds like an appositional usage.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, proper nouns (such as place names or organization names) do not follow ordinary prose grammar. Although there are many exceptions, when it comes to such proper nouns, Japanese tends to avoid using の, and English also prefers to join several nouns directly without using prepositions.

- 世界保健機関
  World Health Organization
  <sup>(Not: 世界の保健の機関 or "Organization for Health of the World")</sup>
- 日本電信電話株式会社
  Nippon Telegraph and Telephone Corporation

In a practical sense, if we didn't have these conventions for making proper nouns sound like proper nouns, we would often get confused. For example, 世界保健機関 refers to that specific agency of the United Nations, whereas 世界の保健の機関 would sound like a generic reference to any organizations related to public health around the world.